# CarouFredSel Wordpress Setup

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, installation, caroufredsel

I tested this script in normal .php file but when put code in wordpress header file script doesn't worked. 
Can someone show me how to put CarouFredSel slider inside wordpress theme?
Here is the code i used in .php file and all works just fine:

```
        <!-- include jQuery + carouFredSel plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>

    <!-- optionally include helper plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

    <!-- fire plugin onDocumentReady -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function() {

            //  Basic carousel, no options
            $('#foo0').carouFredSel();

            //  Basic carousel + timer, using CSS-transitions
            $('#foo1').carouFredSel({
                auto: {
                    pauseOnHover: 'resume',
                    progress: '#timer1'
                }
            }, {
                transition: true
            });

            //  Scrolled by user interaction
            $('#foo2').carouFredSel({
                auto: false,
                prev: '#prev2',
                next: '#next2',
                pagination: "#pager2",
                mousewheel: true,
                swipe: {
                    onMouse: true,
                    onTouch: true
                }
            });

            //  Variable number of visible items with variable sizes
            $('#foo3').carouFredSel({
                width: 360,
                height: 'auto',
                prev: '#prev3',
                next: '#next3',
                auto: false
            });

            //  Responsive layout, resizing the items
            $('#foo4').carouFredSel({
                responsive: true,
                width: '100%',
                scroll: 2,
                items: {
                    width: 400,
                //  height: '30%',  //  optionally resize item-height
                    visible: {
                        min: 2,
                        max: 6
                    }
                }
            });

            //  Fuild layout, centering the items
            $('#foo5').carouFredSel({
                width: '100%',
                scroll: 2
            });

        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

        .list_carousel {
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin: 0 0 30px 60px;
            width: 900px;

        }
        .list_carousel ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            display: block;
        }
        .list_carousel li {
            font-size: 40px;
            color: #999;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #eee;
            border: 5px solid #999;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 6px;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        .list_carousel.responsive {
            width: auto;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        .clearfix {
            float: none;
            clear: both;
        }

    </style>

    <p>Basic carousel.</p>
        <div class="list_carousel">
            <ul id="foo1">  
            <?php 
            $html = "";
            $url = "http://rss.dnevnik.hr/index.rss";
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
            for ($i = 0; $i <10; $i++) {
            $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
            $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link; 
            $opis = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;

            $html .= "<li><div><a href='$link'><h3>$opis<h3></a></div></li>";}
            echo $html;
            ?>
            </ul>


            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <br />
```